# jquery find active div

Tags: jquery, class, click, find

hy everyone,

i have simple html code showing a table width

html

```
<table class="table_site">
    <tr>
        <td class="subsite"><a href="#">register</a></td>
        <td class="subsite"><a href="#">login</a></td>
        <td class="subsite"><a href="#">home</a></td>
        <td class="subsite"><a href="#">market</a></td>
        <td class="subsite"><a href="#">mail</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

now i´ve got some script

```
$(function() {
    $('.subsite')
        .click(function(){
            $('.content').empty()
            document.title = '..:: DIELECSUR S.L ::' + $current;
            loadContent($current"_main.html")
            $(this).css("text-decoration", "underline")
        });
});
```

my real question is:
how can i use le shortest code to find the proper content of td.subsite class that when click on it, and use as a variable value to append text converting in a valid url lo load???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is get the text from the link that was clicked on and use it in your jQuery, you can do that like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.subsite').click(function() {
        var text = $(this).find("a").text();
        $('.content').empty();
        document.title = '..:: DIELECSUR S.L ::' + text;
        loadContent(text + "_main.html");
        $(this).css("text-decoration", "underline");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$(function() {
    $('.subsite')
    .click(function() {
        var linkText = $(this).css("text-decoration", "underline").text();
        $('.content').empty();
        document.title = '..:: DIELECSUR S.L ::' + linkText;
        loadContent(linkText + "_main.html");
    });
});
```